# How to add a custom @click Handler to a <router-link>?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a VueJS 3 application, which contains a router-link element. I want to add a custom click-handler. So, instead of navigating to the href-url, instead it shall execute a function in my pinia-store.

```
          <router-link
            :to="{ name: 'disclaimer', params: { lang: currentLanguage } }"
            @click="toggleDisclaimerDialog"
          >
            Disclaimer
          </router-link>
```

I have tried this code and also tried to use `@click.native=`.
However, it always behaves like there was no @click-handler and is redirecting to the URL under "to".
So it executes the javascript-function but then always navigates to the URL under "to".

According to the docs from VueJS, the @click handler should be executed but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I need to encapsulate the label in a `<span>` element adding ".stop.prevent" to the click-event.

```
          <router-link
            :to="{ name: 'disclaimer', params: { lang: currentLanguage } }"
          >
            <span @click.stop.prevent="toggleDisclaimerDialog">Disclaimer</span>
          </router-link>
```